# Hello, I am trying to work with mounted function in vue.js and it is not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I am trying to getallproducts automatically when the following url loadsk

```
'/Admin/ProductsAdmin'
```

but the mounted function is not working it doesnot load anything when url has been loaded
the follwing is my main.js code:-

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        loading: false,
        objectIndex: 0,
        productModel: {
            id: 0,
            name: "Product Name",
            description: "Product Description",
            value: 1.99
        },
        products: []
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getProducts();
        console.log("mounted");
    },
    methods:
    {
        getProduct(id) {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.get('/Admin/ProductsAdmin' + id)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.products = res.data;

                })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
                .then(() => { this.loading = false; });

        },
        getProducts() {
           this.loading = true;
            axios.get('/Admin/ProductsAdmin')
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.products = res.data;

                })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
                .then(() => { this.loading = false; });

        },
        createProduct() {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.post('/Admin/products', this.productModel)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    this.products.push(res.data);
                })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
                .then(() => { this.loading = false; });

        },
       
        updateProduct() {
    this.loading = true;
            axios.put('/Admin/products', this.productModel, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
                .then(() => {
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        },
        deleteProduct(id,index) {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.delete('/Admin/products/' + id)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    this.products.splice(index, 1);

                })
                .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
                .then(() => { this.loading = false; });

        },
        editProduct(product, index) {
            this.objectIndex = index;
            this.productModel = {
                id: product.id,
                name: product.name,
                description: product.description,
                value: product.value,
            };
                
        }

    },
    computed: {

    }

});
```

when i refresh page or load following page mounted function doesnot works it does nothing.Please can anyone help me.

Comment: First, you should make sure `console.log("mounted");` is triggered or not

Answer (score 0):

Use **created**.

Instead of

```
mounted() {
        this.getProducts();
        console.log("mounted");
    },
```

Use one of the **Vue life cycle hooks** which is the `created()`.

```
created() {
        this.getProducts();
        console.log("created");
    },
```